# SQL: How can I display full 7 days of the week with my data that only represents some days of the week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, group-by

I have a table that stores data on days of the week.  I'm wanting to return a row for each day of the week even if there isn't any rows for that day of the week in my table.  Here's my current sql select statement.

```
SELECT StoreID,
   CASE 
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 1 THEN 'Sunday' 
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 2 THEN 'Monday'
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 6 THEN 'Friday'
       WHEN S.[DayOfWeek] = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
       ELSE 'BAD' 
   END AS [DayOfWeek], 
       isOpen
  FROM MyTable S
 WHERE StoreID = @I_StoreID
 ORDER BY S.[DayOfWeek]
```

Right now it returns just a Monday  and Tuesday record because that's all that exists int he table, but I want it to also return the other rows even though there are no records currently for them. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is what I have ...

```
  StoreID | DayOfWeek | isOpen

      22     Sunday      0
      22     Monday      1
      29     Sunday      0
```

Here is what I'm hoping to get...

```
  StoreID | DayOfWeek | isOpen

      22     Sunday      0
      22     Monday      1
      22     Tuesday     NULL
       ....
      22     Saturday    NULL

      29     Sunday      1
      29     Monday      NULL 
      29     Tuesday     NULL
       ....
      29     Saturday    NULL
```

Comment: What should it return for those days where there aren't any records?

Comment: I was thinking NULL values? Maybe this could pose a problem but I haven't currently thought of one. Thanks for the question :)

Comment: You can't "Magically" create data.  You'll either need to create a table iwth this data or "UNION the data in to a virtual set that you use as a join.  LIke "Select Sunday from dual union select Tuesday from dual union select wed..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT
    a.StoreID,
    a.weekdayname,
    b.isOpen
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT StoreID
        FROM MyTable
    ) aa
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 AS weekdaynum, 'Sunday' AS weekdayname UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'Monday'                UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 'Tuesday'               UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 'Wednesday'             UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, 'Thursday'              UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, 'Friday'                UNION ALL
        SELECT 7, 'Saturday'
    ) bb
) a
LEFT JOIN
    MyTable b ON a.StoreID = b.StoreID AND 
                 a.weekdaynum = b.[DayOfWeek]
WHERE
    a.StoreID = @I_StoreID
ORDER BY
    a.StoreID, a.weekdaynum
```

Here, we manually select all weekday names and `CROSS JOIN` them with each distinct `StoreID`. We then wrap the result of that selection in the `FROM` clause and perform a `LEFT JOIN` back onto the main table on the condition that `StoreID` as well as the weekday number match. If not, then the `isOpen` field will be `NULL`, but the `StoreID` and corresponding weekday will still display.

---

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a49d/2/0)

Answer (score 2):

If isOpen is 1 for open, 0 for close you might be able to do

```
select StoreID,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 1 then isOpen else 0 end) as Sunday,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 2 then isOpen else 0 end) as Monday,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 3 then isOpen else 0 end) as Tuesday,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 4 then isOpen else 0 end) as Wednesday,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 5 then isOpen else 0 end) as Thursday,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 6 then isOpen else 0 end) as Friday,
   max(case when s.[DayOfWeek] = 7 then isOpen else 0 end) as Saturday
from MyTable S
where StoreID = @I_StoreID
group by StoreID
```

This will change the format of the query but should give you 1 column for each day of the week and if the store is open that day.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I changed this before I saw your updated response. Given the data you want to see, the other answer should work better.**

Do you have a table independent of MyTable that has DayOfWeek? If there's not a single record in the entire table with a DayOfWeek = 1, then you have to bring in possibly a separate DayOfWeek table to list these values, before you start using the MyTable.

Here's a hypothetical DayOfWeek table and the SQL that would result:

**DayOfWeek Table**
DayOfWeek : Name
1 : Sunday
2 : Monday
3 : Tuesday
4 : Wednesday
5 : Thursday
6 : Friday
7 : Saturday

**Query**

```
SELECT D.Name,
S.isOpen,
COUNT(S.StoreID) as StoreID_Count
FROM DayOfWeek D
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable S ON S.DayOfWeek = D.DayOfWeek
WHERE S.StoreID = @I_StoreID
GROUP BY D.[DayOfWeek], S.isOpen
ORDER BY D.[DayOfWeek]
```

I believe this should get you close at the very least.

Comment: no quite (i dont think) I've edited my original post with my result set I'm hoping to get.  Perhaps the question is more clear now. Thanks!