# SQL force insert dummy data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CTE with the following statement to obtain the total break time of a user in a day.

```
CTEBreak as
(
    select max(name) as Name
          ,sum(DurationInHours) as HourlyBreak
          ,Work_Day
    from ctesemifinal
    where id in (4130)
    group by Work_Day
)
```

This returns results like:

[image]

However if they did not take a break for a particular day, it results into:

[image]

where some days are not included because he didn't take breaks. What I want is to force insert a '1' in the days that the user didn't take breaks. How do I accomplish this? Thank you!

Btw, the Work_Day column is a datename of an actual date (just in case it might come to play)

Comment: Create a table with the days of the week, left join your CTE to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How can I display full 7 days of the week with my data that only represents some days of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714390/sql-how-can-i-display-full-7-days-of-the-week-with-my-data-that-only-represents)

Comment: @MatSnow that post and mine are slightly similar, however the key point that I was missing was including the isnull in my select statement which Dave thankfully answered and was not needed(??) in the other post. Thank you though. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide SQL Server with all the data you want to include in your query, either from a table in your database, via calculation or by explicitly including it.

In your case, you can explicitly include it here by adding another `cte` that includes your days of the week and `left join`ing from that to your `CTEBreak`:

```
with
...
,CTEBreak as (...)
,CTEWorkdays(wd) as (select 'Monday' union all
                     select 'Tuesday' union all
                     select 'Wednesday' union all
                     select 'Thursday' union all
                     select 'Friday'
                    )
select isnull(b.HourlyBreak,1) as HourlyBreak
      ,w.wd as Work_Day
from CTEWorkdays as w
    left join CTEBreak as b
        on w.wd = b.Work_Day
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a similar method earlier but was using the CTEBreak as my main "table" when joining. You're awesome.

Comment: No, *you're* awesome, @JorelMolato

Answer (score 1):

I want to note that you can often solve this sort of problem with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when id = 4130 then name end) as Name,
       max(case when id = 4130 then DurationInHours else 1 end) as HourlyBreak,
       Work_Day
from ctesemifinal
group by Work_Day;
```

This assumes that all work days are in the original data.  This approach can be simpler than the `left join` under some circumstances.